# Get value from multiple input boxes that have incremental id's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the value from the select element with jquery, but the console.log is showing that the value is NaN. I think it may have to do with the way I am selecting the ID's, but I am not sure.

```
//Here I am creating the select element with the options in a loop and giving them an incremental ID.
var div = $('<div class="containter">');
    $('.rForm').append(div);
    for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {

        var h3 = $('<h3 style="margin-bottom: 5px;">' + "Question" + " " + (x + 1) + '</h3>');

        var label = $('<label>').attr('id', 'q'+ (x + 1)).text(questions[x]);
        var br = $('<br>');
        div.append(label);
        div.append(br);
        var select = $('<select>').attr('id', 'q'+ (x + 1));

        for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if(i === 0){
                select.append($('<option>').text(options[i]));
            }
            else{
                select.append($('<option>').attr('value', options[i].val).text(options[i].text));
            }

            console.log('hi')
        }
        $('.containter').append(select);

    }


$('#submit').on('click', function(){

            // var answers = [];


            var newProfile = {
                name: $('#name').val().trim(),
                photo: $('#link').val().trim(),
                scores: []
            }

            for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++){
                var num = $('#q' + (x+1)).val(); //Showing the value as NaN
                console.log("num", num)
                newProfile.scores.push(parseInt(num));
            }

            console.log('new', newProfile);
            console.log('scores' + newProfile.scores);

        });
```

Comment: sorry, questions is defined, Ill update code

Comment: _"Here I am creating the select element"_ Where is `select` appended to `document`?

Comment: added more code for details, but yes, it is appended to a html file

Comment: Where are `options` and `questions` defined? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Options and questions are both arrays I have defined, Ill modify code

Comment: `var num = $('#q' + (x+1)).val(); //Showing the value as NaN`. Cannot reproduce `NaN` https://jsfiddle.net/szkxhfdn/

Comment: I am aware it is showing as NaN

Comment: What is showing as `NaN`? The `.value` of `select` element is logged at `console` at linked jsfiddle. Cannot reproduce `NaN`.

Comment: what does that mean? I was thinking 'num' is showing as a NaN

Comment: Does that mean, I am either not referencing the ID correctly or not appending the select elements correctly? I checked in browser, and all the select tags have the incremented IDs

Answer (score 0):

Rather do this :

```js
var questions = [{
  title: "Do you like jQuery ?",
  expected: [0],
  answers: [
    "yes",
    "no"
  ]
}, {
  title: "jQuery is :",
  expected: [1],
  answers: [
    "a language",
    "a library",
    "a framework"
  ]
}, {
  title: "What is the type of jQuery.map() ?",
  expected: [2],
  answers: [
    "[a] -> b",
    "[a] -> [b]",
    "[a] -> (a -> Int -> b) -> [b]"
  ]
}];

$("form").html($.map(questions, function (q, i) {
  return ""
  + "<div>"
  +   "<h3>" + q.title + "</h3>" 
  +   "<select "
  +     "multiple "
  +     "name=\"q" + i + "\""
  +     "size=\"" + q.answers.length + "\""
  +   ">" 
  +     $.map(q.answers, function (a, j) {
          return "<option value=\"" + j + "\">" + a + "</option>";
        }).join("") 
  +   "</select>"
  + "</div>";
}).join("") + (
  "<button type=\"button\">Submit</button>"
));

$("button").click(function () {
  var score = 0;
  var $sel = $("select");
  $sel.each(function (i) {
    var answers = $(this).val() || [];
    var expected = questions[i].expected;
    if (answers.join() == expected.join()) score++;
  });
  alert(score + "/" + questions.length);
});
```

```css
body, h3, select, input {font: normal 12px Arial;}
select {overflow: hidden;}
div {margin-bottom: 1em;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form></form>
```

Comment: Is the way I did it the reason the value is coming out as NaN for 'num' variable?

Comment: @ANonymous It depends partly on the elements of the `options` array, but you did not show us what's inside of it... Maybe you think that your HTML generator is more interesting... But there is another problem, what happens if you select the first option (i = 0) ? There is no value set for this option, then I guess `parseInt` will fail and yield `NaN`. Try `parseInt("")`. Anyway, *you should start with static HTML code*, written by hand, not generated, with only one or two select elements and a few options. You'll face the exact same problem but it will be far easier for us to check...

Comment: @ANonymous And to answer your comment, yes, the way you do is likely to produce bugs. Try to organize your code better. However, I repeat, before having fun with generated HTML, replace what's in your question with a hard coded version.